# How to fix signup error when signup was actually successful in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express

[image]  i try to signup in my login page built with react and backend in express js and database is postgres. when i signup using a new email address for the first time, i get An error occured during signup and when i check the db, i see that the newly registered email is in the database, how do i resolve this error?

my signupage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SignupForm from '../components/SignupForm';

function SignupPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <SignupForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignupPage;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignupForm() {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const isValidEmail = (email) => {
    // Simple regex for basic email validation
    const re = /^(([^<>()\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email.toLowerCase());
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setError('');
    
    if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      setError('Please enter a valid email address.');
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      });

      // Handle success (e.g., display a message, redirect to login page, etc.)
      console.log(response.data);
      history.push('/login'); // Redirect to login page after successful sign up
    } catch (error) {
      // Log the exact error and set it to state to display
      console.error('Signup error:', error.response || error);
      //console.error('Signup error:', error.response?.data || error);
      setError(error.response?.data?.error || 'An error occurred during signup.');
    }
    
  };
```

authcontroller.js

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        // Check if email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already registered' });
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10); // Hash the password

        const newUser = await User.create({
            email,
            encrypted_password: hashedPassword,
            created_at: new Date(),
            updated_at: new Date()
        });

        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully', userId: newUser.id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Registration error:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
};
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: it says email already registered

Comment: Do you mean that when you create a user with a new email address and no user in the database, it still means that the email is already in use?

Comment: yes, abasolutely

Comment: When you look at your database, is the user still created?

Comment: yes, it's in the description of the question

Comment: Are you calling `handleSubmit` twice? The `register` request is present twice in the network log.

Comment: @3limin4t0r ,please where?

Comment: You changed the screenshot. You say "i get An error occured during signup" yet your screenshot doesn't show an error. You also didn't post the error or stack trace. So I don't quite understand what the problem is. The current screenshot does show a 201 (created) response, which indicates success.

Answer (score 0):

First, `clear your database` and please try it this way:

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        // Check if email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
        if (!existingUser) {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10); // Hash the password

            const newUser = await User.create({
                email,
                encrypted_password: hashedPassword,
                created_at: new Date(),
                updated_at: new Date()
            });

            return res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully', userId: newUser.id });
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already registered' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Registration error:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
};
```

Comment: it said An error occured during signup and the newly emai is seen in the database

Comment: Can you debug using your browser's console and send the complete error and make sure you've cleared the database please?

Comment: i have attached the screeenshot of teh error

Comment: Please provide the result of your request in the console and then in ***"Network"***.

Comment: i have edited it now and clicked sign up just once